# How namespaces/zookeeper chroots work together in Apache Curator

Tags: apache-zookeeper, chroot, apache-curator

Do chrooted paths and *namespaces* mean the same thing in *Apache Curator*?

E.g. if we create curator with `myserver:2181/pathA`, does it mean *namespace* will be set to `pathA`?

Or, if *namespace* is set to `pathA`, does that equal to setting zk path to `myserver:2181/pathA`?

If anyone could compare common usages of the two, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like *namespaces* and *chroot paths* work independently of each other. Namespaces are not aware of chroots and treat them no different than regular zk paths.

If namespace is set, it will be applied on top of existing chroot path.

Chrooted paths by themselves do not set corresponding namespaces, however, one would assume the similar behavior between adding chroot to zk path or setting a namespace. One major difference is that one cannot "unset" chroot path, whereas namespace can be overridden.